# SQL Server : Pivot and unpivots

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot this SQL Server table, however I'm struggling to wrap my head around what I need to do. I can do a basic pivot, however this has become very challenging. I am in essence to convert the table below to

```
Company Code    Account Class           Period  Billings Collections    Debtors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
500             Accounts Receiveable    1       xx           xx         xx
500             Accounts Receiveable    2       xxx          xx         xx
500             Accounts Receiveable    3       xx           xx         xxx
500             Accounts Receiveable    1       xx           xx         xx
```

to

```
Company Code       Account Class                              1  2   3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
500                Accounts Receiveable       Billings       xx xx  xx
500                Accounts Receiveable       Collections   xxx xx  xx
500                Accounts Receiveable       Debtors       xx  xx  xxx
```

I was planning to to a pivot and on a single column and then join the table with itself, performing another pivot again with itself but I don't capture the column name. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Bluefeet: PIVOT question! :-)

Comment: @marc_s You rang? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your thinking is correct that you'll need to `unpivot` first in order to get the final result that you want.  You'll need to convert your multiple columns of `Billings`, `Collections` and `Debtors` into multiple rows and then pivot the `Period` values into columns.

You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using, but starting in SQL Server 2005 you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot:

```
select 
  CompanyCode,
  AccountClass,
  period,
  [Type],
  Value
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'Billings', Billings union all
  select 'Collections', Collections union all
  select 'Debtors', Debtors
) c ([Type], value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34d9b/3).  This turns your data into the format:

```
| COMPANYCODE |         ACCOUNTCLASS | PERIOD |        TYPE | VALUE |
|-------------|----------------------|--------|-------------|-------|
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |      1 |    Billings |    xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |      1 | Collections |    xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |      1 |     Debtors |    xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |      2 |    Billings |   xxx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |      2 | Collections |    xx |
```

You'll notice that you now have a row for each `Billings`, `Collections` and `Debtors`.  Now you can apply the PIVOT function to the `Period` column:

```
select 
  CompanyCode,
  AccountClass,
  Type,
  [1], 
  [2],
  [3]
from
(
  select 
    CompanyCode,
    AccountClass,
    period,
    [Type],
    Value
  from yourtable t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Billings', Billings union all
    select 'Collections', Collections union all
    select 'Debtors', Debtors
  ) c ([Type], value)
) unp
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for period in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34d9b/4). This gives you a result of:

```
| COMPANYCODE |         ACCOUNTCLASS |        TYPE |  1 |   2 |   3 |
|-------------|----------------------|-------------|----|-----|-----|
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |    Billings | xx | xxx |  xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable | Collections | xx |  xx |  xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |     Debtors | xx |  xx | xxx |
```

Now if you have the possibility that the `CompanyCode` and `AccountClass` could appear multiple times for the same `Period`, you'll need to create a value that can be used to return multiple distinct rows.  In this case, you'd need to use a windowing function similar to `row_number()` to create a unique sequence for these combinations.  I'd modify the code above slightly to:

```
select 
  CompanyCode,
  AccountClass,
  Type,
  [1], 
  [2],
  [3]
from
(
  select 
    CompanyCode,
    AccountClass,
    seq,
    period,
    [Type],
    Value
  from
  (
    select CompanyCode, AccountClass, Period, Billings, 
      Collections, Debtors,
      seq = row_number() over(partition by CompanyCode, AccountClass, Period
                              order by CompanyCode, AccountClass) 
    from yourtable
  ) t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Billings', Billings union all
    select 'Collections', Collections union all
    select 'Debtors', Debtors
  ) c ([Type], value)
) unp
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for period in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34d9b/11). You'll notice that this changes the result slightly to:

```
| COMPANYCODE |         ACCOUNTCLASS |        TYPE |  1 |      2 |      3 |
|-------------|----------------------|-------------|----|--------|--------|
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |    Billings | xx |    xxx |     xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable | Collections | xx |     xx |     xx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |     Debtors | xx |     xx |    xxx |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |    Billings | xx | (null) | (null) |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable | Collections | xx | (null) | (null) |
|         500 | Accounts Receiveable |     Debtors | xx | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: See - you do know the answer! :-)

Comment: Wow that is extremely comprehensive. Unforunately when I try to apply your method I am getting errors. I will have to dig even further into this.

Comment: @Calgar99 What's your error?  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: MS SQL, Im trying to apply the second method you offered however the error is that it does not recognize any of the columns already predefined ie(CompanyCode = Invalid Column Name)

Comment: Ignore, It was late and I was being a dope, calling the wrong table. Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.  First you need to UNPIVOT `Billings`, `Collections`, and `Debtors` then PIVOT `Period`.

```
declare @table table
    ([CompanyCode] int, [AccountClass] varchar(20), [Period] int, [Billings] varchar(3), [Collections] varchar(3), [Debtors] varchar(3));

INSERT INTO @table
    ([CompanyCode], [AccountClass], [Period], [Billings], [Collections], [Debtors])
VALUES
    (500, 'Accounts Receiveable', 1, 'xx', 'xx', 'xx'),
    (500, 'Accounts Receiveable', 2, 'xxx', 'xx', 'xx'),
    (500, 'Accounts Receiveable', 3, 'xx', 'xx', 'xxx'),
    (500, 'Accounts Receiveable', 1, 'xx', 'xx', 'xx');

SELECT *
  FROM (
         SELECT [CompanyCode], [AccountClass], [Period], [Type], [Value]
         FROM @table
         UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR [Type] IN ([Billings],[Collections],[Debtors])) AS u
       ) as t
  PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Period] IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS pvt;
  -- use SUM(Value) if Billings/Collections/Debtors are numeric columns
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
CompanyCode AccountClass         Type         1    2    3
----------- -------------------- ------------ ---- ---- ----
500         Accounts Receiveable Billings     xx   xxx  xx
500         Accounts Receiveable Collections  xx   xx   xx
500         Accounts Receiveable Debtors      xx   xx   xxx
```